# how to decrease the effect of NA data in taking the Mean?

Tags: r, mean

I have a data set which i need to take the mean of each row

```
  A B  C
  2 3  5
  5 5  4 
  NA NA 6
  NA NA 5
  NA NA 7
  NA NA NA
  NA NA 5
  NA NA 4
  2 5  8
```

I already following function but i want to have as much available  data as i  can.

```
Mean<- apply(DF, 1, mean)
```

Comment: There's a `rowMeans` function that has an `na.rm` argument, i.e. try `rowMeans(DF, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this (`na.rm` argument of `mean` function allows you to ignore `NA`):

```
Mean <- apply(DF, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Output for your example:

```
> Mean
[1] 3.333333 4.666667 6.000000 5.000000 7.000000      NaN 5.000000 4.000000 5.000000
```

Comment: i use it but i have still too much NA data

Comment: @Madamespring, so how do you define mean from only `NA` values?

Comment: actually i have lots of rows with just one available value, so i want to have a mean value for those part.

Comment: I don't understend you, what would be your expected output in your example?